# jquery-ui-multiselect-widget flickering while loading the data?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

jQuery MultiSelect UI Widget 1.14pre

This is an issue for me with the long list.
See the below image for the onload and after load effect(click on link).

I just tested a list of 1600 items on a mozilla machine and the browser locked up for about ~5 minutes.

https://camo.githubusercontent.com/3dc1a939065e6364e699eef8f08b9cd653741cf0/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f333439313130312f3335313235362f61636133333962652d613034322d313165322d393462382d3239396561333065663532632e706e67

Example: Suppose i need to show 1000 names in Drop Down on a web page i am using multiselect.js. when this web page is loading all the names are coming in  `<select><option</option></select>` tags. after completing the loading this is becoming multiselect drop down.

```
$(function(){
    $("#"+ prefix + "schedule_id").multiselect({
      header: 'Travels',
      noneSelectedText: 'Travels',
      selectedText: 'Travels',
      prefix: prefix + 'travels',
    }).select2;
});
```

** While loading the data in drop down it is flickering. as i showed in image 
1) while loading the page/data.
2) After loading the page/data.

Is there any suggestion how to solve this??

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that its something in the way your AJAX data is loading - possibly causing successive re-initializations.  Try to get the full data to load into a value element completely before initializing/resetting the drop down.

Alternatively, you could consider storing a data-set of dropdown options as a text file and have that text file load as the option content instead of live AJAX. This would work well if the the option content doesn't change too quickly. (You could run a separate cycle to regularly update the option text file when it needs to be)

The third option I would recommend, is to use a google type filtered selector instead. So that the whole 1000 option list is searched through for matches, instead of trying to render the whole scrollable list.